# UITextField text replaces with same text while scrolling in uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

[image][image: Check this image][image]I placed three textfields in one row and 1 textfield in another row. I took all the textfields in one array and wrote the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
            tf.delegate = self;
            tf.tag = 16;
            tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];
            [tf release];

            UITextField *tf1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 10, 100, 30)];
            tf1.delegate = self;
            tf1.tag = 17;
            tf1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:tf1];
            [tf1 release];
        }
        else {
            UITextField *tf3 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
            tf3.delegate = self;
            tf3.tag = 18;
            tf3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:tf3];
            [tf3 release];

        }

    }
    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:16];
    tf.text =  [m_textFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITextField *tf1 = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:17];
    tf1.text =  [m_textFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITextField *tf3 = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:18];
    tf3.text =  [m_textFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // cell.textLabel.text = @"Hiiiii";
    return cell;
}
```

and in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method wrote as follows.

```
[textFieldsDataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:currentIndexPath.row withObject:textField.text];
```

My Problem is once i enter text in one textfield and scroll up and down then that same text is taking to remaining two textfields in that same row.

and if i enter text in three textfields and then scroll , that is taking text from the last textfield for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are having an issue with cell reuse.

To increase performance, UITableView will reuse a cell off screen instead of creating a new cell. When a cell gets reused, it does not clear it out. Its your job to reassign what information you want in it.

you set the information something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]

    // If the cell is nil, it is a new cell and you need to init it    
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // setting the cell's information
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I wrote as i edited now check it once ...once enter text in first textfield, if i scroll up and down that same text is taking to second text field also in the same row....

Comment: can you put all your code in code blocks? its a pain to read it like that

Comment: were you able to figure it out?